# Unable to insert write data conditionaly inside trigger (IF, CONCAT, IFNULL) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, conditional-statements

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Update_Member
AFTER UPDATE ON `member` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE changeNote VARCHAR(5000) DEFAULT '';

SET changeNote = IF(OLD.Name != NEW.Name, 
                    CONCAT( changeNote, 
                            'Name(', 
                            IFNULL(OLD.Name, '--'), 
                            '->', 
                            IFNULL(NEW.Name, '--'), 
                            '), '
                          ), 
                    changeNote);

SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM changeNote) INTO changeNote;

INSERT INTO `member_change_log`(`Name`) VALUES(changeNote)

END
```

The above trigger does not insert any data when the name contains null. Could anyone please what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above trigger does not insert any data when the name contains null. Could anyone please what is wrong with my code.

If `NEW.Name` is NULL then `OLD.Name != NEW.Name` is NULL too, and IF() executes alternative variant, i.e. you obtain

```
SET changeNote = changeNote
```

Simply swap variants:

```
SET changeNote = IF( OLD.Name = NEW.Name, changeNote, CONCAT( ... ) );
```

If both `OLD.Name` and `NEW.Name` may be NULL then use null-safe compare operator `<=>` instead of regular compare `=`.